# postgres function does not exist when call with Callable in Java JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I called a postgresql function with Callable in JDBC, but it show exception
"function does not exis"

```
con = dataSource.getConnection();
con.setAutoCommit(false);
CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{call myfunction(?)}");
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.REF_CURSOR);
stmt.execute();
con.commit();
```

However, when i add
`stmt.setObject(1, null);`
before registerOutParameter , it works.
I can not understand what happen

Comment: You don't need a CallableStatement, to call a function. Just run regular `select myfunction(?)` through a PreparedStatement.

Comment: if use PreparedStatement, we will can not get Output

Comment: Use: `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` and process the `ResultSet`